# A shell script (.sh) that calls an infinite loop called by another script to run in the background

Tags: linux, bash, shell, background-process

Essentially what is happening is I'm operating on a limited instruction set framework (to run on an embedded device). The idea is very simple.

I call a script which makes two files:

- file A: start_up - which calls the infinite loop
- file B: background_while - which repeats a process over again

**contents of file A:**

```
#!/bin/sh
sh background_while&
```

**contents of file B:**

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
 #some commands
 sleep 5
done
```

I would like to terminate this process called in the background. Could someone show how this is best done using a keyboard interrupt?

Comment: "From a keyboard interrupt"? Pardon? After your script A has exited, what's going to read and operate on that interrupt?

Comment: so it's this "main script" in which you'll be receiving an interrupt from the user at some point in the future, at which time you want to shut down process-B? **At minimum**, that script's existence should be unambiguously covered in your question. Knowing what it's doing at the point in time when we're waiting for an interrupt (literally -- just sitting around looping `sleep`? Waiting for some other foreground process? something else?) is also rather critical.

Comment: @Charles
What happens is this. I have a main script. From the main script, I echo the contents of file B into into file B, then I echo the contents of file A into file A. 

then from the main script, I call sh fileA (which runs the file). What I want to do now is stop this while loop in the background from executing its commands.

The main script has no purpose other than setting some otherwise unused variables.

The main script simply does:
A) sets some variables (unused)
B) creates file B with contents file B
C) creates file A with contents file A
D) calls file A to execute file B

Comment: I still don't think I understand the intent behind this question. What's the difference between the answer you accepted (which extends scriptA to call `wait` explicitly) and not backgrounding scriptB at all (which *automatically* calls `wait` before going on to the next command)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scriptA just ends after calling scriptB as a background then you cannot continue waiting for a keyboard interrupt. So, instead of immediately ending scriptA you can have a tight loop and wait for a signal, then kill your background processes by using `trap`.

Something like:

**scriptA**

```
#!/bin/bash

function kill_background(){
   kill ${myPid}
}

trap kill_background SIGINT

bash ./scriptB.sh &
myPid=$!

wait
```

Your scriptB will be the same. `$!` gets the pid of the last command executed (your scriptB) and `wait` makes scriptA wait for all background processes to return. `trap` will catch interrupt signals and kill your scriptB.